# How to display custom "Access Denied" page when an user tries to view a page that doesn't exist in nginx web server?

Tags: nginx

I created a new file `/usr/share/html` called `access-denied.html`. It contains "Access denied".

I've apache server running at port 8080 and nginx is running at port 80. I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy server.

```
server{
listen 80;
server_name test-reverse-proxy.com ;
location / {
proxy_pass http://192.168.169.149:8080/;
}
location /access-denied{
root /usr/share/nginx/html/access-denied.html;
try_files /access-denied.html =404;

}

}
```

Currently when I enter something except / in the browser, for example `http://192.168.169.149/dffdsf` I get 404 Not Found.

I want this to be replaced by "Access Denied".

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

First write a working config without the special behaviour (what you've shown us here won't work even if you remote the access-denied location block.

Secondly, returning a "access-denied" message is somewhat pointless if its accompanied by a 404 status.

```
error_page 403 404 =403 /access-denied.html;
root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

location / {
...
```

Comment: This doesn't work!